# How can I do an HTTP redirect in C++

Tags: c++, http, redirect

I'm making an HTTP server in c++, I notice that the way apache works is if you request a directory without adding a forward slash at the end, firefox still somehow knows that it's a directory you are requesting (which seems impossible for firefox to do, which is why I'm assuming apache is doing a redirect).

Is that assumption right?  Does apache check to see that you are requesting a directory and then does an http redirect to a request with the forward slash?  If that is how apache works, how do I implement that in c++?  Thanks to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determine if the resource represents a directory, if so reply with a:

```
HTTP/1.X 301 Moved Permanently
Location: URI-including-trailing-slash
```

Using 301 allows user agents to cache the redirect.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I did and it worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this, you would:

1. call stat on the pathname
2. determine that it is a directory
3. send the necesssary HTTP response for a redirect

I'm not at all sure that you need to do this. Install the Firefox 'web developer' add-on to see exactly what goes back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, this should not be a problem. Suggestions for how to proceed:

- Get the source code for Apache and look at what it does
- Build a debug build of Apache and step through the code in a debugger in such a case; examine which pieces of code get run.
- Install Wireshark (network analysis tool), Live HTTP Headers (Firefox extension) etc, and look at what's happening on the network
- Read the relevant RFCs for HTTP - which presumably you should be keeping under your pillow anyway if you're writing a server.

Once you've done those things, it should be obvious how to do it. If you can't do those things, you should not be trying to develop a web server in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is correct and make sure your response includes a Location header to the URL that allows directory listing and a legal 301/302 first line. It is not a C++ question, it is more of a HTTP protocol question, since you are trying to write a HTTP server, as one of the other posts suggests, read the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

You should install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) and observe the HTTP headers sent by other web servers.

Your question is impossible to answer precisely without more details, but you want to send an [HTTP 3xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_304#3xx_Redirection) status code with a `Location` header.